# counter_cache in single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, single-table-inheritance, counter-cache

I am wondering if the counter_cache would work in single table inheritance.

For these models:

```
class User
  has_many :questions
end

class Question
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end

class SimpleQuestion < Question
end
class ComplexQuestion < Question
end
```

So will the following counters work?

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.integer :questions_count
  t.integer :simple_questions_count
  t.integer :complex_questions_count
end
```

1. All of them work
2. None of them work
3. Only `questions_count` work
4. Only `simple_questions_count` and `complex_questions_count`

Which one? I am guessing the 3rd, but I want 4 more. If it's not 4, how do I make 4 work?

=== UPDATE ===

Here is an example:

```
id, user_id, question_content, type
1, 3, something, SimpleQuestion
2, 3, something, SimpleQuestion
3, 3, something, ComplexQuestion
```

So now I want:

```
user.questions_count # => 3
user.simple_questions_count # => 2
user.complex_questions_count # => 1
```

My question is, what's the basic behavior of `:counter_cache => true` and is it possible to apply on single table inheritance?

Comment: Are you trying to have `simple_questions_count` and `complex_questions_count` return the same count number? Or are those going to count based on some other field on the question table (eg. User submits whether it's simple or complex question)?

Comment: `SimpleQuestion` and `ComplexQuestion` are sub-classes of `Question`, having different `type` in the same table. Maybe I give an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking through the source code where ":counter_cache" is implemented, it does not look like it supports the sort of counting you need. Fortunately, it is easy to roll your own here. Just update Question to track the counts manually, like so:

```
class Question
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :increment_counts
  before_destroy :decrement_counts

  protected

  def increment_counts
    User.increment_counter :questions_count, user_id
    User.increment_counter "#{type.pluralize.underscore}_count", user_id
  end

  def decrement_counts
    User.decrement_counter :questions_count, user_id
    User.decrement_counter "#{type.pluralize.underscore}_count", user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use `after_create` instead of `after_save`? So you mean the `counter_cache` would not work for `questions_count`? How about `simple_questions_count` and `complex_questions_count`? They would work on `belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It should be afer_create, not after_save. Just a typo on my part. For questions_count, "counter_cache => true" would work, but I figure if you're going to have manual counter callbacks anyway, might as well put the questions_count logic there too. For simple_questions_count and complex_questions_count, Rails currently offers no built-in solution -- that's what the manual callbacks are for.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet above to fix the after_create typo.

Answer (score 11):

Just faced the same situation and it worked for me as you expected (num 4):

Look, modify your code like this, so that sub-classes would override parents behavior:

```
class User
  has_many :questions
end

class Question
  belongs_to :user
end

class SimpleQuestion < Question
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end
class ComplexQuestion < Question
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end
```

And add `complex_questions_count` and `simple_questions_count` columns to your `User`

Thats it! whenever you create a are question it would increment the proper counter. Tested it on rails 3.2!